# Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.24.2 and electron@7.1.2

Tags: node.js, firebase, electron

I'm trying to use firebase JS SDK with Electron in WebStorm, however, when I import the Firebase SDK, install it with npm and try to launch the app, I get an error:

```
    Cannot find module 'E:\Projects\Project\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary
                                       \electron-v7.1-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node'
```

When trying to rebuild the app as some posts suggested

```
npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=7.1.2 --python="E:\Python\python.exe"
```

I get another error:

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.24.2/electron-v7.1-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.24.2 and electron@7.1.2 (electron-v7.1 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 response downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.1.2/node-v7.1.2-headers.tar.gz
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (E:\Node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\install.js:187:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:317:22)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (E:\Node\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\request.js:1066:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:601:27)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:116:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:470:22)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:305:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:341:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:316:11)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
```

What should I do at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using LTS version of NodeJS.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's helpful to include an explanation too.